# Javax.Swing; How can I create an object of a different class and assign variables received from the jframe ? Conceptual issue

Tags: swing

I am working for the first time with javax.swing and jframes, so please excuse me if you find this question primitive.

Problem: In my main function I have created an object of a class lets say ClassTest. So the code goes like:

```
      import TestPackage.ClassTest.*;

      public class Qinterface extends JFrame and implements ActionListener
      {
      public string Login;

      public static void main(String[] args){
      ClassTest test = new ClassTest();
      try{ eventqueue invoker ...}catch{}
      }


    Qinterface(){
    setResizable(false);
    setTitle("Carrefour : Qualys Application");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(300, 100, 850, 500);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    txtEnterText = new JTextField();
    txtEnterText.setText("Enter Qualys Login");
    txtEnterText.setBounds(10, 193, 166, 23);
    contentPane.add(txtEnterText);
    txtEnterText.setColumns(10);

        btnSubmit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {  
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent eSubmit)
        {
            //button is pressed
            System.out.println("You clicked the button Submit");
            Login = txtEnterText.getText();}});

           }
              }
```

So as seen in the last line of the code I am able to get the value from the txtEnterText field and assign to a local variable "Login". But how do i go about if I want to assign this value to an instance of a class created in the main function, for example;

```
            test.x=txtEnterText.getText();
```

I know its not possible in this approach as we are in the constructor the Qinterface class and the variable of the ClassTest instantiated in the main are not visible.

So the question is general and conceptual; how do you go about such kinds of problems to resolve them, when coding with javax.swing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a login process as an example:

Your interface class could hold a "LoginData" object that is populated by the action listener. By providing a getter for the data object, the login data can then be accessed from outside of the interface.

This is just one of the many ways you could tackle this problem.

This would be a good candidate for MVC architecture - you can read about it a little [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).